# Is the trapezoidal approximation of an integral exact in a symmetrical case?

Tags: calculus

I'm taking a calculus II class and doing pretty well in it, but I have no other background in formal mathematics or proofs. I saw the Wikipedia page for the Trapezoidal Rule, [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) The picture seems to depict a situation where treating the curve within its bounds, in addition to the line forming the top of the Trapezoid, as a single shape, would produce a shape that's symmetric (or at least, it suggests it enough that I could imagine it). So you could cut one piece off at the intersection point and lay it down on top of the other and they'd fit perfectly. Again, I don't have any more formal language to describe this, I'm just curious and my professor doesn't seem to know anything about the theory. So here's the question:

If the intersections of line formed by the top of a single, non-composite trapezoidal approximation, and the curve that it is approximating, form a shape with a certain kind of symmetry, is it possible that that approximation becomes exact? Not just "so good you can't tell the difference," but definitionally the same value?

Again, I hope this isn't a stupid question. I'm just taking this course for compsci.

Comment: There is no stupid question but sometimes stupid answers. By the way, *Welcome to the site !*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that can totally happen. In fact, you might know from your calc course that the integral is *linear*. That is, $$\int_a^b f(x) + g(x) \ \text{d}x = \int_a^b f(x) \ \text{d}x + \int_a^b g(x) \ \text{d} x$$ Well, if you're not doing a whole trapezoidal Riemann sum, and just looking at one trapezoid as part of the approximation, then you're approximating $$ \int_a^b f(x) \ \text{d}x \approx\int_a^b h(x) \ \text{d}x $$ where $f(x)$ is the function you want to get the area under and $h(x)$ is a linear function giving the height of the trapezoid. Well, by the linearity of the integral, those two terms are equal exactly when $$ \int_a^b \left(f(x) - h(x)\right) \ \text{d}x = 0$$ Intuitively, this makes a lot of sense. The approximation will be exact if and only if the distance between them has as much positive contribution as negative contribution (and therefore integrates to $0$). In the case you're describing, the simplest case, your saying $$ \int_a^{a + b/2} (f(x) - h(x)) \ \text{d}x = -\int_{a + b/2}^{b} (f(x) - h(x)) \ \text{d}x$$ holds because the difference between the curves has the same shape in the first region as the second, just on different sides, so the total integral becomes $0$. And that means the approximation will  be exact. Althought it won't happen often without constructing it, it's easy to construct many similar cases where the curve might exhibit much less clear symmetry, but the difference integrates out to 0. In the symmetric case though, it's nice and easy to see the difference integrates away, so the approximation becomes exact.

Comment: Thanks! That's really cool.

Comment: @phdavis1027 Welcome to MSE.  If this answered your question,  click the check box to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

That is a very interesting question.

I think you are talking about cases like the one shown in the diagram below:

[image: PICTURE OF SOMETHING LIKE A CUBIC POLYNOMIAL WITH A SINGLE TRAPEZOID DRAWN]

There is definitely some symmetry going on here. However, the term "*symmetric function*" is already reserved for something else in mathematics.

Suppose that a function $G$ is a *symmetric function*.
If $G(1) = \pi$, then $G(\pi) = 1$.
The numbers $1$ and $\pi$ are not special.
Saying that a function is *symmetric* is equivalent to saying that $G(G(x)) = x$
(for all $x$ which are valid inputs to function $G$).

Let us say that a function with your special property is called, "*Temmetric*"

Mathematicians invent new words in almost every paper they public. If you ever write a proof someday, then I hope that you to feel free to invent new words. If you think it would be useful to have a name for something, then give that thing a name. This is fine, as long as you write down an explanation (definition) of what your made-up word means.

#### Definition of *Temmetric*

> We define a continuous real-valued function $F$ to be *Temmetric* if there is a point on the x-axis and there is a non-zero distance **Δ**, such that if $d$ is any distance smaller than **Δ**, then $F(x - d) = F(x + d)$.
>
> ---
>
> In this context, a *distance* is a non-negative decimal number, such as $0, 0.5, 1, 712 + \pi, \text{etc.}$

#### Example of a *Temetric* Function

Let $\mathtt{P}$ be a function such that for any decimal number $x$, $\mathtt{P}(x) = x^3 + 5*x^{2}$

We shall show that $\mathtt{P}$ is a *Temmetric* function.

[image: PICTURE OF x^3 + 5*x^2]

We have a point on the x-axis, $x = \frac{-5}{3}$, such that:
  if
    $Δ = \frac{-5}{3}$
  then
   if
    $\delta$ satisfies $0 \leq \delta \leq Δ$
   then
      $P(x - \delta) = P(x + \delta)$

The indentation above might look a little funny. However, I find that indentation  makes it easier to read run-on sentences (long sentences). Computer programmers use indentation to format very long clause written in computer code. Otherwise, computer programs would be unreadable.

#### Conjecture Regarding Temmetric Functions

Let $F$ be a Temmetric function

Suppose that $s$ is a point on the x-axis such that **Δ** is a decimal number (real number) such that for any decimal number $\delta$ if $0 \leq d \leq Δ$ is any distance smaller than **Δ**, then $F(x - d) = F(x + d)$.

Let $a$ be an arbitrary positive decimal number smaller than **Δ**.

Then,
  the area under curve $F$ from $x = s - a\quad$ to $quadx = s + a$
    is equal to
  the surface area of the trapezoid whose four corners are the points:
    $(s - a, 0)$
    $(s - a, F(s - a))$
    $(s + a, F(s + a))$
    $(s + a, 0)$